# Lower-bound wildcard в Java - какой смысл? Реальные сценарии использования?

Tags: java

Пытаюсь постичь смысл использования lower-bound wildcard. Какие реальные преимущества он дает?

Представим ситуацию:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
```

И такой дженерик:

```
List<? super B>
```

Что из этого следует?

1. Фактический тип может быть: **Object**, **A**, **B**
2. Возвращаться из такого листа в любом случае будет **Object**
3. Внутрь такого листа мы можем положить только **B** или его наследники

С первыми двумя пунктами всё понятно, а вот третий вызывает вопросы.

```
List<? super B> sup = new ArrayList<>();
sup.add(new A()); // ERROR
sup.add(new B()); // OK
```

В первом случае мы не можем положить в **sup** объект **A**, т.к. не знаем фактический тип (вдруг это **В**). Но ведь компилятор считает всё внутри **Object**`ом и нам в любом случае надо будет делать кастинг при получении! Какой смысл в таком ограничении? Ведь оно легко обходится через присвоение ссылки, например, на **List< Object>**, в котором может быть вообще что угодно.

```
List<? super B> sup = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(new A()); // OK
a.add(new B()); // OK
a.add(new Number() { ... }); // OK

sup = a; // OK
```

Так зачем городить весь огород с контравариантностью, если фактически никаких гарантий мы не получаем? Можно же указать **List< Object>** без всяких wildcard`ов и получить, по сути, то же самое? Разница всего лишь в том, что в варианте с **super** исключаются присвоения типа

```
List<? super B> sup = new ArrayList<C>();
```

...хотя фактически под видом **Object**`а можно будет пропихнуть всё, что угодно?

Comment: ну а зачем нужно наследование или композиция, или вообще классы - можно же просто создать 1 класс, нафигарить методов в нем и все счастливы :)

Comment: Джошуа Блох "Java Эффективное программирование", глава 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дженерики были созданы для типизации, а не для коллекции (хотя ассоциация у большинства такая).

Можно найти использование **super wildcard**-а в другом месте.

Представим, есть интерфейс **Function с дженериком T**,  и одна из его реализации **FunctionImpl**, который обслуживает объектов **A**, (следовательно и **B**).
Есть другой метод(**bar**), который принимает объект типа **B** и ещё объект типа **Function**,чтобы вызвать его с переданным объектом **B** и логировать.
Так как для него все равно что это за функция, он может принимать любую, лишь бы он мог вызываться с объектом **B**, тогда тип параметра такой функции можеть быть либо **B**, либо его предки(**A**).

```
void main() {
    Function<A> func = new FunctionImpl();
    bar(new B(), func);
}

void bar(B b, Function<? super B> f) {
    System.out.println("Handle B: " + b.getName());    
    f.foo(b);
    System.out.println("Bye");
 }

interface Function<T> {
    void foo(T t);
}

class FunctionImpl implements Function<A> {
    public void foo(A t) {
        System.out.println(t.anyField);
   }
}
```

Рекомендую прочитать про **PECS**.

Answer (score 1):

Небольшая модификация исходного примера, чтоб сделать все еще более интересным:

```java
List<? super B> sup = new ArrayList<Object>() {
    {
        add(new A()); // OK
        add(new B()); // OK
        add(new Integer(42)); // OK
    }
};

sup.add(new B()); // OK
sup.add(new A()); // Error
```

Все правильно, потому что `sup` в данном случае это ссылка на коллекцию, а что в коллекции неизвестно, но компилятор проверит, что через ссылку `sup` с wildcard `? super B` в качестве аргументов не будут переданы объекты отличные от типа B и его наследников. Но так обычно не пишут, вот более приближенный к реальности пример:

```java
static <T> void copyEven(List<? extends T> source, List<? super T> destination) {                                                                                                                        
    for (int i = 0; i < source.size(); i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            destination.add(source.get(i));
        }
    }
}

class Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}

List<Animal> zoo = new ArrayList<>();
List<Cat> bigCats = new ArrayList<>();

copyEven(bigCats, zoo); // все хорошо, мы можем больших кошек поместить в зоопарк
copyEven(zoo, bigCats); // ошибка компиляции: нельзя произвольных животных смешивать с большими кошками
```

---

Отчасти вина в сложности понимания wildcard'ов лежит в том числе на неправильном выборе ключевых слов в языке Java, в новых языках вместо `? super B` будет написано `in B`, а вместо `? extends B` будет `out B`, с использованием этих ключевых слов сигнатура функции `copyEven` станет чуть более очевидной:

```
static <T> void copyEven(List<out T> source, List<in T> destination) { }
```